# use makeActiveBinding inside a package

Tags: r

I simply need a R  function like:

```
> la. <- function (envir = globalenv()) {ls(all = T, envir = envir) }`
```

with an active binding so I do need to type brackets

```
> makeActiveBinding('la', la., globalenv())
```

So that

```
> la
[1]  "la"  "la."
```

I now want to implement function `la()` and it bind `la` inside a package
So that when I load the package, `la` is ready available.

How can I bind function `la.()` to the symbol `la` within the package environment?

What value shall I pass to the `envir` argument of function `makeActiveBinding()`

Thanks for any help

Comment: The given solution don't pass the CMD check for me because the active binding is evaluated and fails.

Comment: An additional issue is documenting active bindings, I didn't manage to do it without triggering annoying warnings when loading the workspace.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Check [my new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70722230/1968), it passes `R CMD check`, generates proper documentation, and shouldn’t trigger any warnings.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably something to do in the `.onLoad` function, something like this in your package:

```r
NAMESPACE <- environment()

la. <- function(){ 
  ls(all = T, envir = globalenv())
}

.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  makeActiveBinding("la", la., NAMESPACE)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `namespaceExport` manually causes `R CMD check` to complain. Instead, the export declaration should be put into the `NAMESPACE` file.

Or, when using ‘roxygen2’, add the `@export` tag in front of a dummy `NULL` object to make it generate the appropriate documentation and `NAMESPACE` export declaration:

```
#' List objects
#' @usage la
#' @name la
#' @export
NULL

makeActiveBinding(
    'la',
    function () ls(envir = globalenv(), all.names = TRUE),
    environment()
)
```

Where

- `@usage` causes ‘roxygen’ to generate a “Usage” section, which would otherwise be missing
- `@name` tells ‘roxygen2’ the object name, to be used for the export declaration and for the name of the help page (this can be overridden with `@rdname` if necessary)
- `@export` marks the name as exported, as usual.

Note also that the use of `.onLoad` is not required to declare active bindings: they can be defined directly at namespace/file level.

Comment: You're so good.... I should give you 100 rep. pts. But you got too many already!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

Lets write two functions inside a package:

```
# function one
ll_ <- function(){
  ls(envir = globalenv(), all.names = TRUE)
}

# function two
l_ <- function(){
  ls(envir = globalenv(), all.names = FALSE)
}
```

then write your onLoad() function

```
# Runs when package is loaeded
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  ns <-  asNamespace(pkgname)
  makeActiveBinding("ll", ll_,  env = ns) 
  makeActiveBinding("l", l_,  env = ns) 
  namespaceExport(ns, c('ll','l'))
}
```

When loading your packages, commands l and ll. run functions l() and ll()

Finally, I am sure that by embedding all function in a list and playing with functionals, the definition of onLoad() may become much lighter

Thanks Romain for your suggestion